# Understanding the parameters of a functions provided through manual

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Laser system. The system comes with it's own manual, including an SDK reference, but I need help on understanding the definition of a function included in the reference:

[image]

and

[image]

To use this function, I have this code:

```
private void BrightnessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double setBrightness;
    laser.setDispBrightness(out setBrightness);
}
```

But it keeps giving me this error:

> may not be passed with the 'out keyboard'"  << I think you meant 'keyword'

They also provided me with the sample code below:

[image]

How can I make this work? Any help in understanding how to program just simply the brightness would be appreciated. I am having trouble understanding what to put in for the parameters. Thanks

Comment: Please provide code and other details as formatted text, not as links to off-site pictures.  As for the error, are you sure that is *the exact error message*?  Copy and paste the *exact* error message.  Show the code where you try to invoke the method and get the error.  Show the definition for the method you're trying to invoke.  From the description it just sounds like you're trying to call a method and you're providing an `out` parameter but the method doesn't have an `out` parameter.  But if that's the case then it's not really clear what's being asked either.

Comment: Wihtout seeing the definition of `laser.setDispBrightness` it is hard to say what you are doing wrong.

Comment: It wouldn't make logical sense (to me) to pass the new brightness in as an `out` param.  I assume that the param would need to be set to whatever the new brightness value should be.  A value between 0 and 1.0.  Try removing the `out` keyword.  Also, it looks like you need to pass in a reference to instrument that you're trying to control.

Comment: Another reminder to **NEVER USE IMAGES TO POST TEXT** in a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use an `out` variable when calling the **get** versions of the function. When calling the **set** versions of the function, you should have already set a value for the variable:

```
private void BrightnessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double setBrightness = .5; // set to 50%
    laser.setDispBrightness(setBrightness);
}
```